# Export Mathematica Animation With Retina

Tags: export, animation

Right now I have:

```
animation = 
 Table[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi}], {a, Pi, 
   0, -0.1}]
Export["~/animation.mov", animation, "FrameRate" -> 60]
```

but the result is fuzzy.

I tried increasing ImageSize but that just made a bigger blurry video. How can I increase the DPI?

There is some sort of metadata associated with this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586732/how-can-i-retain-2x-pixel-density-when-encoding-retina-screen-capture-with-ffmpe

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/how-does-quicktime-player-know-when-do-play-a-video-in-hidpi-retina-2x-mode

I made screen recording with a higher pixel density and found.

```
com.apple.quicktime.pixeldensity
```

present in the file

Comment: Without your data, we cannot say anything. Show me what you're trying to do?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I want to increase the pixel density

Comment: You don’t even show us a picture? We have to guess what is hidden in your line of code there?

Comment: @AlexTrounev pick any graph does not matter

Comment: @AlexTrounev I’m asking about the export process

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added the line of code

Comment: Yes, when compared with `animation.gif`, it looks worse.

Comment: @AlexTrounev To me it looks the same as the gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce what you say. Increasing `ImageSize` increases the graphics size (but not the text size within the graphics!) without making it blurry.

I suggest you use `Rasterize[..., ImageResolution -> a*72]` *on each frame* to increase the frame size `a`-fold. The export the list of frames.

Comment: I want 2x pixel-density like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586732/how-can-i-retain-2x-pixel-density-when-encoding-retina-screen-capture-with-ffmpe

Comment: ImageResolution increase the frame size but not the pixel density

Comment: When I open the movie in QuickTime it opens at 720x652 but I want it to open at 360x326 with double the density. Rising the video player window works but I want it to open with the correct size.

Comment: @2426021684 Does QuickTime (or any movie format at all!) encode pixel density at all? I highly doubt that it does. If you know it does, can you provide a link that explains this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586732/how-can-i-retain-2x-pixel-density-when-encoding-retina-screen-capture-with-ffmpe

Comment: There is metadata to provide that see ^

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/how-does-quicktime-player-know-when-do-play-a-video-in-hidpi-retina-2x-mode

Comment: @2426021684 This appears to be an uncommon, vendor-specific tag that almost certainly cannot be added directly with Mathematica. I suggest you look for ways to add it through post-processing. Frankly, I would suggest you just export frames as PNGs from Mathematica and assemble them into a video with other tools, as this way you will have much more flexibility than what Mathematica could ever provide.

Comment: I decide to make an html file and specify width so the video is played with the correct dimensions